# Is there any difference in Oracle provider for Entity Framework between standard & enterprise?

Tags: oracle, entity-framework

[image]

I find myself in a position to work on Oracle Express for a project. Just curious will it continue to work with given provider in enterprise edition?

Is there any difference in Oracle provider for Entity Framework between Oracle Express & Enterprise Edition 12c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will work. ODP.Net (managed and unmanaged) can connect to all versions of Oracle and also to any platform. A good starting point to read is the [Oracle Data Provider for .NET FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/faq-093106.html)

And no, there is no difference.